# Using the reduce method to extract information from an object

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to use the reduce array method to extract the key values from an object and return a new array with only the values listed. Here is my code:

```js
function extractValue(arr, key) {
  let newArr = []
  return arr.reduce(function(accum, nextVal) {
    if(nextVal !== key)
      newArr.push(accum[key] + ', '+ nextVal[key])
      return newArr
  })
}

let data = [ { name: 'bob'   }
           , { name: 'jim'   }
           , { name: 'sarah' }
           , { age: 100      }
           ]
console.log( extractValue(data, 'name'))
```

For some reason, when i log my function to the console my results keep turning out like this,
`["bob", "jim", undefined, "Sarah", undefined, undefined]`.
How can I prevent the undefined results from showing up?

Comment: Why are you using `reduce` for this? Is it mandatory?

Comment: Yes it is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using reduce isn't quite right... it should be more like:

```
arr.reduce(function(accum, item) {

}, defaultValue);
```

Every iteration you must return the accumulator, regardless of the condition.

As you want to return another array, your defaultValue makes sense to be an empty array:

```
arr.reduce(function(accum, item) {

}, []);
```

Overall, the code which will work will be something like the following:

```
function extractValue(arr, key) {
  return arr.reduce(function(accum, item) {
    if (!item[key]) {
      return accum;  // <--- we must still return the accumulator
    }

    accum.push(item[key])
    return accum;  // <---- and return accumulator here also
  }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter in advance and map the wanted value.

```js
function extractValue(arr, key) {
    return arr
        .filter(object => key in object)
        .map(object => object[key]);
}

console.log(extractValue([{name: 'bob'}, {name: 'jim'}, {name: 'sarah'}, {age: 100}], 'name'));
```

By using `reduce`, you need to return the former accumulator if the property does not exists.

```js
function extractValue(arr, key) {
    return arr.reduce(function(accum, object) {
        if (key in object) accum.push(object[key]);
        return accum;
    }, []);
}

console.log(extractValue([{name: 'bob'}, {name: 'jim'}, {name: 'sarah'}, {age: 100}], 'name'));
```